# What is the functional group derived from benzene called?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

If you were asked in an exam to name this functional group, would you call it benzene or an aromatic hydrocarbon?

[image: skeletal structure of benzene]

Comment: It's not a functional group, it's a molecule. If it were to be bonded something else within a molecule, then it would be called a phenyl group.

Comment: I would call it an arene, but if you're just worried about your exam, why ask us? You should probably ask your teacher because they are who will be marking your script.

Comment: I know it is a molecule, what functional group would it be in?

Comment: And I'm studying by myself at home, I don't have a teacher with me at this very moment

Comment: Functional groups derived from benzene are various aryl groups like phenyl, three phenylene groups etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Benzene" characterises a compound and not a functional group, "Aromatic Hydrocarbon" characterises a class of compounds. I would call your structure as a functional group, "phenyl".

Comment: Is Benzene a Phenyl then?

Comment: Benzene is the name of an actual compound. Phenyl is the name of a functional group. The structure you drew can be seen to represent either a "real" compound and then you call it "benzene" or it can represent the abstract concept of a functional group and then you call it "phenyl". You might say for example that benzene is an aromatic hydrocarbon and that phenyl is an aromatic functional group